# Telerik RadGrid doubleclick edit event not working on server but is on local

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have this site that a team and I have been working on, and I have been encountering the same problem for a while. On a few pages I am using a Telerik RadGrid, and there is a doubleclick event function on the rows (which is in the RadCodeBlock) which works when I run it off my own machine. But it doesn't seem to be working when I run it off the server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide any code, it's kind of hard to help you.
I'll still try to help you by showing the code I am using:

Code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnRowDblClick = "RadGrid_RowDblClick";
    }
```

aspx file:

```
<telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="scriptBlock" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RadGrid_RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {
            editedRow = eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical();
            $find("<%= RadGrid1.MasterTableView.ClientID %>").editItem(editedRow);
        }
    </script>
</telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

I also know I've had issues in the past while using `RadCodeBlock` and I would recommend you use `RadScriptBlock` instead. As discussed [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-radscriptblock-radcodeblock.html), `RadCodeBlock` may interfere with your `RadAjaxManager`.

Comment: Hey Francis, Thanks for the idea. I changed my RadCodeBlock to a RadScriptBlock, but this did nothing to help the situation. The only problem I have is that the doubleclick does not work when I run it off the server. Could this be something to do with IIS?

Comment: Same i am facing, have you find any way out?